# plot a bar chart using groupby function and plotly and streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, pandas-groupby, plotly-python

i am trying to plot a bar chart based on groupby function but once i try it crash and display the below error:

this error below appear when the user select 3 items from the `multiselect` widget.

> ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of
> argument `color` is 3, whereas the length of previously-processed
> arguments ['gender', 'count'] is 95

## code:

```
some_columns_df = df.loc[:,['gender','country','city','hoby','company','status']]
some_collumns = some_columns_df.columns.tolist()

select_box_var= st.selectbox("Choose X Column",some_collumns)
multiselect_var= st.multiselect("Select Columns To GroupBy",some_collumns)  

test_g3 = df.groupby([select_box_var] + multiselect_var).size().reset_index(name='count')
fig = px.histogram(test_g3,x=select_box_var, y='count',color=multiselect_var ,barmode = 'group',text_auto = True)
```

**I know the error is in the `color` parameter in the `px.histogram`**

Comment: Did you use Colab for it ?

Comment: no i did not use google colab neither jupyter notebook

Comment: Would you upgrade plotly `pip install plotly --upgrade`

Comment: plotly version  = 5.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is color only accepts one category.

```
color=['column_a','column_b']
```

Would cause

> ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument `color` is 2, whereas the length of  previously-processed arguments ['total_bill'] is 244

`2` is the length of list `['column_a','column_b']`, while `244` is the `dataframe`'s rows.

According to the [document](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.express.histogram.html):

> **color** (str or int or Series or array-like) – Either a name of a column in data_frame, or a pandas Series or array_like object. Values from this column or array_like are used to assign color to marks.

Therefore, either we use a `column_name`, or we use a `series`.
Here's my approach:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips() # a data set from plotly
df.head()
```

Output

```
  total_bill   tip     sex smoker  day    time  size
0       16.99  1.01  Female     No  Sun  Dinner     2
1       10.34  1.66    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     3
2       21.01  3.50    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     3
3       23.68  3.31    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     2
4       24.59  3.61  Female     No  Sun  Dinner     4
```

Column:
`sex` with unique values `Female` and `Male`

`time` with unique values `Dinner` and `Lunch`
I choose these two columns, it's easier to figure out that there is only
4 combination.

We create a `series` that concat columns `sex` and `time`

```
categories = df[['sex','time']].agg(', '.join, axis=1)
print(categories)
```

Output

```
0      Female, Dinner
1        Male, Dinner
2        Male, Dinner
3        Male, Dinner
4      Female, Dinner
            ...      
239      Male, Dinner
240    Female, Dinner
241      Male, Dinner
242      Male, Dinner
243    Female, Dinner
Length: 244, dtype: object
```

---

Utilize this `categories` as color reference

```
fig = px.histogram(df, x="total_bill", color =categories)
fig.show()
```

[image]

---

If `','.join` didn't work, having issue,

```
categories = df[['sex','time']].agg(', '.join, axis=1)
```

then we try another way

```
categories = df['sex'] + df['time']
```

Sup[1]

[image][image]

Comment: i tried your answer but it display the below error:
`TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found`

Comment: It means the data include `None`, this happens like: `','.join([None])`. You may clean the dataset, or find yourself dataset without `None`, `np.NaN`.

Comment: Instead, you may use `df['A'] + df['B']` for convenient first. put this issue aside.

Comment: yes i search about it and i filtered the **None** using :
`result = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x if x is not None else '', df))`
but now it display this :
`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: sorry i did not understand your last comment

Comment: The key is we trynna create a new column `df['C']` that concat the string of `df['A']` and `df['B']`, as shown in the pics above. Sup[1]

Comment: i `fillna()` for now  and first i tried without the `join` it works and display the chart but once i tried with `join` it crash and display this error:
`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Never mind, your know the concept, how about you find yourself a proper dataset to try it out.

Comment: thank you for your help i will but what this error mean ?

Comment: does your `dataframe`'s index isn't numerical integer? probably need to reset the index

Comment: the dataframe's index is integer

Comment: Then, I have no idea about it, the scope belongs to **data cleaning** aspect. The dataset somehow doesn't perfect at all.